# Refresh Current/Active Component (Not Reload) on Modal Close

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, router

**Scenario:** I want to refresh (Not Reload) the component **(Active URL)** on Login Modal Close.

**Flow:** I have a current Active URL. When User clicks on LOGIN BUTTON, a Modal Gets Open. On Success, modal gets close and user lands up on same page.

Current URL ----> Header Component----> Login Modal----(**on success**)----->current URL with Updated data

**Problem:** On Modal Close**(ON SUCCESS ONLY)**, how to current refresh the component, not reload and call services.

**R&D :** Angular doesn't call **constructor()** and **NgOnInit()** if component doesn't get destroyed

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, you are pointing current URL -> as a header component, which is incorrect, you don't say where the header component lives, is it in the app component directly ? Is it on a page component? When a modal closes you can access the promise. Maybe you want to use ngOnChanges(simple: SimpleChanges) and see if an input has changed and update it in header component. As I can understand the modal changes an input of the header component. If that doesn't help you, post your code in order to see what you are doing.

```
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialog, {
      width: '250px'
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
       // fetch you new navigations
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: May be you are correct The question is little Vague. Basically header is global which contains different Navigation for different components.

Currently After Login Success I want to Update the component data which is not happening becoz component isn't destroyed yet
@tenten Thnx for answering.

Comment: @Nelson_John Ok, so the header component lives in the app component. The login button is in the header component? If so, access the afterClosed promise from the modal and fetch only the new navagations. Most of the dialogs have this logic
```ts
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }
```
observable or promise

Comment: thanks For this reference. I'll Execute it. @tenten